# Single year interval on dateplot x axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dateplot

I am plotting a time series with weekly resolution. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        height=0.6\linewidth,
        axis lines=left,
        ymin=0,
        ylabel={Price},
        date coordinates in=x,
        x tick label as interval,
        xticklabel={\year}
    ]

    \addplot 
    [draw=black, mark=none]
    table {
        2009-01-02 31.42
        2009-01-09 29.64
        2009-01-16 27.44
        2009-01-23 27.92
        2009-01-30 28.6
        2009-02-06 28.16
        2009-02-13 27.65
        ... more data ...
        2014-10-24 36.51
        2014-10-31 37.06
        2014-11-07 37.61
        2014-11-14 39.95
        2014-11-21 41.76
        2014-11-28 43.38
    };

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this, with more than one of the same year:

[image]

I would like a single year in each interval on the x axis, with ticks to mark the boundary between two years, like this:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your complete dataset look like? (Could you pastebin it or something?)

Comment: Here is the same code as above, but with all the data: http://pastebin.com/v4uyA2nh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up faking it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\linewidth,
        height=0.6\linewidth,
        axis lines=left,
        ymin=0,
        ylabel={Price (NOK)},
        ylabel near ticks,
        minor xtick=\empty,
        xtick={52, 104, ..., 260},
        xticklabel=\empty,
        xmajorgrids=true,
    ]

    \addplot 
    [draw=black, mark=none]
    table {
        0   31.42
        1   29.64
        2   27.44
        3   27.92
        4   28.60
        ...
        306 39.95
        307 41.76
        308 43.38
    };
    \end{axis}

    \foreach \year [count=\i] in {2009, 2010, ..., 2014}{
        \node at (-1.1 + 2.2*\i, -1em) {\year};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I changed the date coordinates to a simple counter and placed the year labels manually. The offset and increment for the labels were found by trial and error.

[image]

This version also gives me a strange error:

> ```
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
> <to be read again> 
>                    p
> l.330     \end{axis}
>
> A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
> (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
> look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
> ```

The line number points to where `\end{axis}` is, so is there something wrong with the `axis` specification?. Any ideas what's causing this?

Edit: The `Missing number, treated as zero` error goes away if I take out `minor xtick=\empty` from the axis options. The output is apparently the same.